# Help to compute all powers $A^{n}$ and find is the matrix of $A$ diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I have a matrix:

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

which satisfies: $A\left( e_{1}\right)=e_{1},A\left( e_{2}\right)=ae_{1}+e_{2}, a\neq 0$

I need compute all powers $A^{n}, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and find their matrices.

$$
A^n=
\begin{bmatrix}1 & na \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is it true?

Is there a basis of $V$ (if $V$ is a 2-dimensional real vector space with basis $\left\{e_{1},e_{2}\right\}$) so that the matrix of $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: Before asking whether it is true you could have computed atleast $A^2$ to get some idea....

Comment: $$
A^2=
\begin{bmatrix}1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2a \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$
A = I+ N = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} + \pmatrix{ 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 }.
$$
Then $N$ is nilpotent and $N^2=0$. Now
$$
A^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} N^k = I+ {n\choose1} N = I + nN =\pmatrix{1&na\\0&1} ,
$$
where I used the convention $N^0=I$.

Answer (score 3):

The formula is clearly true for $n=0$. Use induction for positive and negative $n$ to show that the formula is always true.

If the matrix was diagonalisable, then you would have
$A = V \Lambda V^{-1}$ for some invertible $V$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. However, in this case it is easy to compute the eigenvalues and derive a contradiction.

**Addendum**: My logic above could be clarified slightly. Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are all one, then we must have $\Lambda = I$ and hence $A=I$, a contradiction. Hence $A$ cannot be diagonalised.